# Which Design Pattern / RTTI

Tags: c++, design-patterns, rtti

I'm looking for the best way to dispatch objects to the correct "target" object.

I have a base command class: Cmd, two sub-classes: BufferCmd and StateCmd.  Command "GotoLine" is derived from BufferCmd and "ChangeCmd" is derived from StateCmd.  BufferCmds are intended to go to a Buffer class and StateCmds are intended to go to a State object.

I currently have a Visitor pattern set up so that I can do something like:

```
Buffer buffer;
State state;

Cmd *c;
GotoLineCmd gotoCmd = new GotoLineCmd (15);
ChangeCmd changeCmd = new ChangeCommand (...)

c = &gotoCmd;
c->accept (buffer);
c = &changeCmd;
c->accept (state);
```

I want to use the Visitor pattern because I'd like to be able to do something roughly like:

```
Cmd *cmds [5];
cmds [0] = new GotoLineCmd (...); 
cmds [1] = new CopyLineCmd (...); 
cmds [2] = new PasteCmd (...); 

foreach (Cmd *c in cmds) {
    c->accept (buffer);
}
```

Unfortunately in order to use this I need do know what object to send the command to.  I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
Derive Buffer from Commandable
Derive State from Commandable

Commandables *commandables [1] = {new Buffer (), new State () };

// Then have the foreach type statement look like:
foreach (Cmd *c in cmds) {
    c->accept (commandables);
}
```

Is there a pattern that is most appropriate for this type of situation?  Should I even be using the Visitor pattern?  Obvious I want to avoid this:

```
foreach (Cmd *c in cmds) {
    foreach (Commandable *cmdAbles in commandables) {
        if (c->accept (commandables)) {
              // Okay command accepted... 
              break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds more like you want the aptly-named [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

The key is to move the differing parameters of `accept()` into the constructor of each class derived from `Cmd`.  For example, `GotoLineCommand`'s constructor would take the line and the buffer objects as parameters to its constructor, and it would store a pointer or reference to the buffer object.

Once you've done that, you no longer need the parameters to `accept()` and the interface is the same across all classes derived from `Cmd`

```
class Buffer
{
   public:
      void gotoLine(int line);
};

class Cmd
{
   public:
      virtual void accept() = 0;
};

class GotoLineCommand: public Cmd
{
   public:
      GotoLineCommand(Buffer & buffer, int line) :
         buffer_(buffer),
         line_(line)
      {
      }

      virtual void accept()
      {
         buffer_.gotoLine(line_);
      }

   private:
      Buffer & buffer_;
      int line_;
};
```